# SQL Server 2008 - SELECT to combine multiple records (per ID) in to one record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to query the Student (`STU`) & Programs (`PGM`) tables and return one combined record per `ID`, even if there are multiple `PGM` records per `ID`.  I thought about using `GROUP BY STU.ID, STU.FN, STU.LN`, but then I'm not sure how to use `PGM.CD` in the `SELECT`, since it's not an aggregate function or in the GROUP BY clause.`

The `PGM` table may or may not have records.  My query below returns these possible results:

1. If there are no `PGM` records, only one result per `ID` is returned and
   the `PGM.CD` column returns `NULL` (or `''` per the `CASE`).
2. If there's only one record in the `PGM` table, and `PGM.CD = 200`
   (`'DLA'` per the `CASE`), then only one result per `ID` is returned.
3. If there's only one record in the `PGM` table, and `PGM.CD <> 200`
   (`''` per the `CASE`), then only one result per `ID` is returned.
4. If there is more than one record in the `PGM` table (per `ID`), i.e.
   121, 200, 156, this produces multiple rows per `ID`.

I need a query to return only one row per `ID`, combining the results of the `PGM.CD` column.  The `PGM.CD` column should only return `''` or `200` (`'DLA'` per the `CASE`)

```
SELECT STU.ID, STU.FN, STU.LN,
  CASE PGM.CD
    WHEN '200' THEN 'DLA'
    ELSE ''
  END
FROM STU
LEFT JOIN PGM
  ON STU.ID = PGM.PID
```

This is what my query returns (**Without** the `CASE` modifying `PGM.CD`):

```
STU.ID  STU.FN  STU.LN  PGM.CD  
1000    Bruce   Wayne   NULL  
1001    Clark   Kent    200  
1002    Barry   Allen   151  
1002    Barry   Allen   101  
1003    Hal     Jordan  126  
1003    Hal     Jordan  200  
1003    Hal     Jordan  101
```

This is what my query returns (**With** the `CASE` modifying `PGM.CD`):

```
STU.ID  STU.FN  STU.LN  PGM.CD  
1000    Bruce   Wayne   
1001    Clark   Kent    DLA
1002    Barry   Allen   
1002    Barry   Allen   
1003    Hal     Jordan  
1003    Hal     Jordan  DLA
1003    Hal     Jordan
```

I need it to return this:

```
STU.ID  STU.FN  STU.LN  PGM.CD
1000    Bruce   Wayne   
1001    Clark   Kent    DLA
1002    Barry   Allen   
1003    Hal     Jordan  DLA
```

I hope all of this makes sense.  Thanks for the help.

Anthony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a simple query like this:

```
   WITH CTE_PGM
    AS
    (
        SELECT PGM.PID, MAX(  CASE PGM.CD
        WHEN '200' THEN 'DLA'
        ELSE ''
        END) AS MaxCD
        FROM PGM
        GROUP BY PGM.PID
    )
    SELECT STU.ID, STU.FN, STU.LN, MaxCD
    FROM  STU
    INNER JOIN CTE_PGM ON STU.ID = CTE_PGM.PID
```

Try to use the SQL Fiddle(!) it is a big help in a quick answer.

I made an [Example for you](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ed3a/1) how is it working. Pls check it.

Comment: Thank you.  I had to change it to a `LEFT JOIN` because it wasn't returning every record in the `STU` table (not all students have a record in the Programs table), but once I did that, it's working perfectly.  Thanks for the info about SQL Fiddle(!).  I didn't know about that.

Comment: Somebody from this site showed me that too, it is very usefull:) I'm happy that it could help you!

Comment: András, If you have a moment to look at my comment to Mehdi below, can you explain why using `WITH AS` (with `MAX CASE`) gave the correct results, as opposed to just using `MAX CASE` directly in the `SELECT`?

Comment: Mehid query returns the same as mine. Duplicate records are not exists there, but may you did not change his query to LEFT JOIN as mine, so that could be the reason.

Comment: Thank you all for your help with this.  I found out why I was getting different results.  I set all queries to use `LEFT JOIN`, but the query by Andras wasn't using a `GROUP BY` clause.  When I started looking at all the results (4505), I found duplicates.  Once I added `GROUP BY STU.ID, STU.FN, STU.LN`, all queries gave the same results (3919).  Thanks gain everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query :

```
SELECT STU.ID, STU.FN, STU.LN, ISNULL(Max( Case When PGM.CD = 200 then 'DLA' Else '' End), '') as PGM_CD
FROM  STU
Left JOIN PGM ON STU.ID = PGM.PID
Group by STU.ID, STU.FN, STU.LN
```

Comment: Thank you.  Your query was returning less results than Andras' above, and when I compared both results to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STU`, Andras' query was correct.  I don't know enough about `WITH AS` and `MAX` to know why that was the case, but it will give me something else to research/learn.  Thanks again.

Comment: Please Check Andras' query result. if result of my query is deferent to result of Andras' query; means that in Andras query result exist duplicate records for some students.

Comment: Anthony wrote that he changed my INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, when he used it, so I think that could be the difference. Because basicly the two query has exactly the same result without the possibility of duplication.

Comment: thank you. I get my mistake in query. I must use left join instead of inner join in my query. please see my edit.

Comment: @mehdilotfi Thank you all for your help with this.  I found out why I was getting different results.  I set all queries to use `LEFT JOIN`, but the query by Andras wasn't using a `GROUP BY` clause.  When I started looking at all the results (4505), I found duplicates.  Once I added `GROUP BY STU.ID, STU.FN, STU.LN`, all queries gave the same results (3919).  Thanks gain everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STU.ID, STU.FN, STU.LN,
  max(CASE PGM.CD
    WHEN '200' THEN 'DLA'
    ELSE '')
  END
FROM STU
LEFT JOIN PGM
  ON STU.ID = PGM.PID
group by  STU.ID, STU.FN, STU.LN
```

Comment: Thank you. Your query was returning less results than Andras' above, and when I compared both results to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STU`, Andras' query was correct. I don't know enough about `WITH AS` and `MAX` to know why that was the case, but it will give me something else to research/learn. Thanks again.